# Mysql row returns last value in array, but I expect the whole row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, php-5.5

Here is my cart code:

```
function cart() {

    $total = 0;
    $item_quantity = 0;
    $item_name = 0;
    $item_number = 1;
    $amount = 1;
    $quantity = 1;

    foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {

        if($value > 0 ) {

            if(substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_"){

                $length = strlen($name - 8);
                $id = substr($name, 8 , $length);

                $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($id)." ");
                confirm($query);

                $titleArr = array();
                while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
                    $titleArr[$id] = $row['product_title'];
                    $product_name = implode(",", $titleArr);
                    $order_product = $product_name . "-". $value;

                    $sub = $row['product_price']*$value;
                    $item_quantity +=$value;
                    $item_number++;
                    $amount++;
                    $quantity++;
                    $id++;
                }
                $_SESSION['item_total'] = $total += $sub;
                $_SESSION['item_quantity'] = $item_quantity;
                $_SESSION['item_name'] = $order_product;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched online for a long time, please advise.

```
$_SESSION['item_name'] = $order_product;
```

It gives last value from fetch_array I want all product title on cart page.

Comment: Because this code overwrite your session data.  You should have to used $_SESSION['item_name'][] = $order_product;

Comment: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Answer (score 1):

Please make `two dimensional Array`, if you want to show all product title on cart page.

Replace this

```
$order_product = $product_name . "-". $value;
```

with

```
$order_product[] = $product_name . "-". $value;
```

Before `while loop` assign the array:-

```
$order_product = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of these changes should work...

This puts the m all into an array...

```
$_SESSION['item_name'] = array();

foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {

    ...

    $_SESSION['item_total'] = $total += $sub;
    $_SESSION['item_quantity'] = $item_quantity;
    array_push($_SESSION['item_name'],$order_product);

    ...
}
```

This puts them into a comma separated string...

```
$_SESSION['item_name'] = '';

foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {

    ...

    $_SESSION['item_total'] = $total += $sub;
    $_SESSION['item_quantity'] = $item_quantity;
    $_SESSION['item_name'] .= $order_product.', ';

    ...
}

$_SESSION['item_name'] = rtrim($_SESSION['item_name'],' ');
$_SESSION['item_name'] = rtrim($_SESSION['item_name'],',');
```

Comment: Thanks barry it works exactly the way i want it to work

Comment: No problem, if it's you selected answer, then it might be appropriate to indicate that by accepting it as you answer (the tick thing).

Answer (score 0):

updated while loop

```
$total  = 0     
while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
    $titleArr[$id] = $row['product_title'];
    $product_name = implode(",", $titleArr);
    $order_product = $product_name . "-". $value;

    $sub = $row['product_price']*$value;
    $item_quantity +=$value;
    $item_number++;
    $amount++;
    $quantity++;
    $id++;
    $total += $sub; 
    $_SESSION['item_name'][] = $order_product;
}
$_SESSION['item_total'] = $total;
$_SESSION['item_quantity'] = $item_quantity;
```